# Android Error Regarding MultiDex

Tags: java, android, android-multidex

I'm getting the following error when I build my application in Android:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: oauth/signpost/http/HttpResponse.class

My build.gradle looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.me.hey"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.semantics3:Sem3Java:1.2.2'
    compile files('libs/Sem3Java-1.2.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: why compile 'com.semantics3:Sem3Java:1.2.2' and compile files('libs/Sem3Java-1.2.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar')? You only need one. Since these are the same.

Comment: The class oauth/signpost/http/HttpResponse.class is present in your more than one library check that...

Comment: I highly doubt you need multidex anyways.